# Hibernate: bi-direction OnToMany

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i have the following structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "requests")
public class Request extends BaseHistory  {
   ...

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<RequestService> services = new ArrayList<RequestService>(0);
   ... }

@Entity
@Table(name = "requestservices")
public class RequestService extends BaseCancellation  {
   ...
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "RequestId")
   private Request request;
   .. }
```

The query:

```
Criteria query = session.createCriteria(Request.class)
        .createAlias("services", "services")
        .add(Restrictions.eq("services.cancelled", type == RequestType.Cancelled))
        .add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.eq("services.state", RequestServiceState.New))
                .add(Restrictions.conjunction()
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("services.state", RequestServiceState.InProcess))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("handler", employeeId)))
                        .add(Restrictions.eq("services.state", RequestServiceState.Pending))
                    )
                .addOrder(Order.asc("services.executionDate"))
                .addOrder(Order.asc("services.executionTime"));
```

And at the end I receive the following SQL:

```
select
        ...
    from
        requests this_ 
    left outer join
        requestservices services1_ 
            on this_.Id=services1_.RequestId 
    // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    left outer join
        requests request4_ 
            on services1_.RequestId=request4_.Id
    where
       ...
    order by
        ...
```

Is it normal behaviour that there is an additional back-way join that connects the child entity with parent's one once again??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't have bi-directional relationship but two uni-directional relationship.

You've to use `mappedby="..."` in `@OneToMany` to have bi-directional relationship.

```
@OneToMany(mappedby="request")
```